# Simple Java Boolean Not Working

Tags: java, char, boolean, equals

I have the following program that goes through a string. If there is a space, print nothing. If the char is uppercase, print 0. If the char is lowercase, print 1.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Blah {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = input.next();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i).equals(" "))
                System.out.print(" ");
            else if (Character.isUppercase(text.charAt(i)))
                System.out.print("0");
            else {
                System.out.print("1");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I get the following 2 errors:

```
char cannot be deferenced
cannot fine symbol: method.isUppercase(char)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `text.charAt(i)` returns a primitive type `char`, which doesn't have the `equals` method. To compare against a reference character, use the equality operator `==`. The reference character must also be surrounded by single quotes, not double quotes.
2. `isUppercase` must be changed to `isUpperCase`:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
       if (text.charAt(i) == ' ')
           System.out.print(" ");
       else if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i)))
           System.out.print("0");
       else {
           System.out.print("1");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks now it runs fine. But there is one problem: if the string looks like this: aBc DEf G. The program doesn't go past the first whitespace. So it only outputs 101 instead of 101 001 0 @manouti

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion You need to use `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()` to read the whole line.

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion If you want to be awesome too, you need to figure out how to solve these problems on your own!